# Псевдорандом в random.chance(list(dict.keys()))

Tags: python

У меня есть класс Player, в нём есть функция getCards(count), которая "раздаёт карты" в определённом кол-ве. Также есть отдельная функция getInfoHands(), которая выводит информацию об текущей "руке" игроков. Моя проблема состоит в том, что при использовании random.chance... в словаре для разных объектов класса, у них одни и те же значения.

```
import os
import time
import random
from loading import load

class Player:
    totalHand = []
    totalScore = 0

    # SetName
    def __init__(self, name = "blank"):
        self.name = name

        # Give cards
    def getCards(self, amount = 1):
        # 6 7 8 9 10 V(2) Q(3) K(4) T(11 or if 2 - 1)
        cards = {'6': 6,
                 '7': 7,
                 '8': 8,
                 '9': 9,
                 '10': 10,
                 'V': 2,
                 'Q': 3,
                 'K': 4,
                 'T': 11}

        for i in range(1, amount):
            self.totalHand.append(random.choice(list(cards.keys())))

def getInfoHands():
    # Computer hand
    print(f"{Computer.name} hand: | ", end = '')
    for i in Computer.totalHand:
        print(f"{i} | ", end = '')


    # Player hand
    print(f"\n{Human.name} hand: | ", end = '')
    for i in Human.totalHand:
        print(f"{i} | ", end = '')


# main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    player_name = input("\nEnter your name: ")

    Computer = Player("Computer")
    Human = Player(player_name)

    Human.getCards(5)
    Computer.getCards(5)

    getInfoHands()

    # Вывод: Computer hand: | 6 | K | T | 9 | 8 | K | 6 | 8 | 
    #        Ker1an hand: | 6 | K | T | 9 | 8 | K | 6 | 8 |
```

Функции выполняются вроде для разных объектов, а значения одинаковые

Comment: P.S Это урезок из кода, не обращайте внимания на лишние import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
# SetName
def __init__(self, name = "blank"):
    self.name = name
    self.totalHand = []    # < +++
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, также была проблема такого формата с totalScore (тоже требовалось ввести в __init__). Можно, пожалуйста, объяснение, зачем все переменные класса инициализировать в __init__ и что будет, если этого не делать?

Comment: Вым надо перечитать раздел `Атрибуты класса`